# How to return gziped API response in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, gzip

I generally using such response syntax:

```
return response()
    ->json(['request'=> $data, 
        'response' => $response, 
        'client' => $client], 200);
```

How could I make it `gzip`ed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's supposed to be configured per webserver basis. So it depends on which webserver you are using.

If it's Apache that you're using, mod_deflate is your place to go: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_deflate.html

For nginx: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/compression/

Comment: Thank you for an answer, but this way I can't to choose it flexible. Right?

Comment: you have a way to only gzip certain paths. Both nginx and apache support it.

Comment: Ok. I see. I have caught it now. Thank you for your support.